# jQuery-UI autocomplete does not display choices

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a jQuery-UI autocomplete function that is loaded before the form it applies to is loaded.

```
$('#groupset').autocomplete({
    source: 'ajax/php/leeruns.php',
    minlength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.item.groupset_id){
            $('#groupsetdesc').val(ui.item.description);
            if(groups.loaded!=ui.item.groupset_id)groups.load(ui.item.groupset_id);
        } else {
            $('#groupsetdesc').val('');
        }
    }
});
```

The relevant html is:

```
<div><label for='groupset'>Groupset Name</label>
    <input name='filename' id='groupset' type='text' value='' ></div>
<div><label for='groupsetdesc'>Groupset Description</label>
    <input name='groupsetdesc' id='groupsetdesc' type='text' value=''></div>
```

If I type "gr" into the input box, Firebug tells me that this JSON is returned:

```
[{"value":"Group_by_Column",
  "groupset_id":"1",
  "description":"12 groups, each of 8 wells from one column",
  "create_date":"2010-02-24 13:27:26"},
 {"value":"Group_by_Row",
  "groupset_id":"2",
  "description":"8 groups of 12 wells, each from 1 row",
  "create_date":"2010-06-02 14:36:33"}
]
```

I expect to see a faux-dropdown including the entries returned from the autocomplete function.  But no choices show up. This is replicable in IE8 and FF4. Any idea what I'm missing?

jQuery v1.5.1
jQuery-UI 1.8.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a beast to solve as the problem wasn't with the autocomplete code at all.  On the same page, I was also loading the jQuery [validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) .  Version 1.7 of validate has some sort of incompatibility with autocomplete.  Once I upgraded validate to v1.8, autocomplete worked again.

I hope this helps someone else.